# Start Workflow everyday

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a custom SharePoint Sequential Workflow. Is there any way to start the everyday at a particular time.

Can I make a SharePoint  workflow wait and start it at a particular time.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think of do to that is to create a timerjob that launches the specific workflow. That would require you to code the timerjob, but as such, launching a workflow from a timerjob is rather easy.

Comment: How do i launch a workflow from a timer job. Steps would be appreciated.

Comment: To create a timerjob: http://www.andrewconnell.com/Creating-Custom-SharePoint-Timer-Jobs

To launch a workflow from code: http://jainnitin2411.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/programmaticallystartsharepointworkflow/